# Properly dereferencing an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, hash

I'm working on a spell checking program for a class and am running into trouble trying to make the hash array accessible to other functions by using pointers.

Below is just a small part of the code since the program is too large to paste. Basic idea of this part of the code is:

-Create array and pointer to array. 
-Hash each word and use the value as index in array. 
-Use pointer to store the hashed value. 
-Access the array using the pointer for the array and hashed value.

As noted below, directly accessing the word stored in the array works, but I get a seg fault when trying to use the pointers to access the word stored in the array.

```
==1845== Invalid read of size 8
==1845==    at 0x401367: load (dictionary.c:133)
==1845==    by 0x40095D: main (speller.c:45)
==1845==  Address 0xfffc3fab8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd


char** hash_array = calloc(HASH_TABLE_SIZE, sizeof(*hash_array));
char*** array_pointer;

// storing the address of the hash array in pointer
array_pointer = &hash_array;

uint32_t* hash_pointer;
hash_pointer = NULL;

uint32_t hash = hashlittle(word_buffer, word_length, 1578459744);
hash_pointer = &hash;

// this prints out the word successfully
printf("word in h-array: %s\n", hash_array[hash]);

// this seg faults
printf("word in h-array: %s\n", *array_pointer[*hash_pointer]);
```

Comment: try `(*array_pointer)[*hash_pointer]`

Comment: I honestly see no sense in `array_pointer` in this code at all. Storing the address of an automatic variable seems rather pointless, especially since its usage later is the very thing that tripped you up. Likewise to `hash_pointer`. Why not just use `hash_array[hash]`. ??

Comment: @Carlos: in `int* x, y;` what is the type of `y`?

Comment: @WhozCraig. I want to be able to access the array outside the function it was created in. The pointers are there because I don't want to create a copy of the array when I pass it to to another function.

Comment: @iharob. Not sure what the relevancy of your question is. I don't have anything like that in my code.

Comment: @Carlos you don't need to load up otherwise-useless pointers to do that. Just send the array address to whatever function you're calling. The parameter list of the function, if properly declared will accept the pointer gleefully. In other words, if you have some function where you call `func(array_pointer)`, then you should be able to simply do `func(&hash_array)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for tip. I'm still a noob and it's been painful these past few days. I redid my code without the use of arrays of pointers, instead using arrays of strings char str[# of strings][length of string]. Takes up a bunch of space, but less painful to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is because of the operator precedence of the dereference operator `*`.

The following are all equivalent:

`*array_pointer[*hash_pointer]`

`*array_pointer[hash]`

`*(array_pointer[hash])`

`*((&hash_array)[hash])`

`*(*(&hash_array + hash))`

The problem is here: `*(&hash_array + hash)`. You're attempting to dereference a pointer to some memory location offset from the location of where the pointer `hash_array` is stored, rather than where it points, which is causing undefined behavior.